# ¿Por qué no puedo usar un case, un sum y rangos de fecha?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select distinct p.identificacion, p.nombre, ef.numFactura, 
sum (case ef.saldo>0 when ef.fechaFactura >='2018/01/01' 
and ef.fechaFactura >='2018/03/31' then 'si' else 'no' end ) as moroso
from encFactura ef 
inner join persona p on p.identificacion = ef.idenPersona
```

SQL me dice que tengo errores de sintaxis en los `<`, `>` y en las letras `then` y `else`, me pueden ayudar a ver donde estoy cometiendo el error.

Comment: La sintaxis del `case` es incorrecta. Dado que no das un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida que esperas obtener, no puedo responder, pues no se entiende lo que quieres lograr con dicha sentencia. Un saludo.

Comment: Bien, a pesar de la falta de claridad de la pregunta, me he arriesgado a responder. De todas maneras te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Hay básicamente 2 errores en tu consulta. Uno de sintaxis y otro de concepto.

Primero, el de concepto: Intentas hacer un `sum()` de un campo de cadena de caracteres, ya que el resultado del case sería una de las cadenas `'si'` o `'no'`.

Segundo, hay 2 formas permitidas para la sentencia case, y tu de alguna forma estás tratando de mezclar ambas.

En una indicas el campo o expresión que quieres evaluar (solo un campo o una expresión que devuelva un valor) junto a la palabra `case`. Luego, una *lista* de valores, el motor evalúa solamente la igualdad del campo o la expresión con dichos valores, algo como:

```
case a.Campo
  when 1 then 'uno'
  when 2 then 'dos'
  else 'más de dos'
end
```

En la otra, solamente colocas la palabra reservada `case` y puedes evaluar expresiones complejas en cada when de la lista, algo como

```
case 
  when a.Campo > 0 and b.Campo < 0 and c.Campo = d.Campo then 'uno'
  when a.Campo < 0 and b.Campo = 0 or c.Campo != d.Campo then 'dos'
  else 'otro'
end
```

Por lo que puedo *imaginar* de tu consulta, lo que buscas iría en la línea de:

```
select distinct 
         p.identificacion
       , p.nombre
       , ef.numFactura
       , ef.saldo
       , case 
           when ef.saldo > 0 and ef.fechaFactura >='2018/01/01' and ef.fechaFactura >='2018/03/31' then 'si' 
           else 'no' 
         end as moroso
  from encFactura ef 
       inner join persona p on p.identificacion = ef.idenPersona
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es que sum está de más, ya que no necesitas sumar sino determinar el estado de la factura. Si las fechas son constantes ponlas en formato ANSI yyyyMMdd (sin /).

Intenta ponerlo así:

```
select distinct p.identificacion, p.nombre, ef.numFactura, 
case when ef.saldo>0 and ef.fechaFactura >='20180101' 
and ef.fechaFactura >='20180331' then 'si' else 'no' end as moroso
from encFactura ef 
inner join persona p on p.identificacion = ef.idenPersona
```